# How would I format this into a Table?

Tags: powershell

I'm able to get this type of text in a .txt file type.  How would I convert these into rows and columns?
I see the pattern is Header is the first quotation, Second quotes is the Value, Then separated by a comma.
***"Header" : "Value" , ...***
How can I work with this pattern?
Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

```
[{
"DateTimeLogged": "2019-11-19 15:40:13",
"DataDateTimeInMicroSeconds": "1574178002315077",
"JSON": {
    "ActivityType": "2",
    "DataDateTime": "1574178002315077",
    "Symbol": "ESZ19_FUT_CME",
    "OrderTypeName": "Limit",
    "Quantity": "1",
    "BuySell": "2",
    "Price1": "312000",
    "Price2": "0",
    "NewOrderStatus": "8",
    "FillPrice": "312000",
    "OrderFilledQuantity": "1",
    "HighPriceDuringPosit ion": "312000",
    "LowPriceDuringPosition": "312000",
    "LastPriceDuringPosition": "312000",
    "TradeAccount": "",
    "P arentInternalOrderID": "0",
    "OpenClose": "2",
    "IsSimulated": "0",
    "IsAutomatedOrder": "0",
    "IsChartReplaying": "0"
}}]
```

Comment: The `[{` and `}]`, are they actually in the text file?

Comment: convertfrom-json

Comment: Yes, those enclose the block of text

Comment: Assuming the above text is the whole text, it is not a valid JSON format. Some modification on the text will be needed. @js2010

Comment: @drew I put in the missing curly brace at the end.

Comment: Assume his original `...` section included a curly bracket which he truncated.

Comment: You are right @js2010 .  I put into notepad++ with JSON and it didnt like it. Bummer.

Comment: Hmm test-json doesn't like the outer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the two properties `"DateTimeLogged"` and `"DataDateTimeInMicroSeconds"` included in the output aswell, but if that is the case, you can flatten the ``JSON` object inside and add these properties to it before output:

```
# read the file and convert fron Json
$json = Get-Content -Path 'D:\data.txt' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Next step is to flatten the data, so all properties are in the same object

```
# append the two top properties to the JSON object, so you can output that as table (csv file)
$flatObject = $json.JSON | Select-Object *, 
                           @{Name = 'DateTimeLogged'; Expression = {$json.DateTimeLogged}},
                           @{Name = 'DataDateTimeInMicroSeconds'; Expression = {$json.DataDateTimeInMicroSeconds}}

# output on console screen. (this will not fit in a Table format)
$flatObject

# output to CSV file to open in Excel. (this will give you the table format)
$flatObject | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\table.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

# output to GridView will show the data as table
$flatObject | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I tried what you were saying @Theo with no luck.  This is best I can do, but was hoping to have the JSON names as Headers of columns. https://imgur.com/a/2Rfh3do

Comment: @MattyS Why _no luck_? It works for me, so what is the problem at your end? The image you show reveals you are not using the underlying JSON property, simply try to display all in the console as table, but that will never fit..

Comment: OK I got it all figured out. Thank you @Theo!  Your Solution helped the most.

Comment: @MattyS There is also the option to show the data in a GridView window. This will display a formatted table. I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments and hopeful speculation, the below should work for you.

```
$TextFile = Get-Content C:\Path\File.txt
$JSON = $TextFile | ConvertFrom-Json
```

You will then be able to do `$JSON.JSON` to get the details there, where as `$JSON.DateTimeLogged` would return `2019-11-19 15:40:13`.

EDIT: For simplicity of comments.

Do `$JSON.JSON | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: This is what I was going for...Id like the columns of JSON names with values going down.  https://imgur.com/a/2Rfh3do